# how do I copy and save the user's single input by multiple times in Django rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I want to save the same user input data multiple times in the same models. it has a field named " quantity " in which the user puts any digits. then my code can save multiple times the input data based on user input quantity.

I write the below code for this matter. but when I use a loop then it does not work. but every time just save data one time, whereas the user puts multiple quantity digits.

My Code is below

view.py

```
class TestAPIBookingOnly(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [UserRenderers]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def post(self, request, format=False):

        rand_string = ""
        for i in range(4):
            rand_string = rand_string + random.choice(string.digits)

        serial = TestBookingSerializer(data=request.data,  partial=True)

        quantity = request.data['quantity']
        print("Quantity is : ", quantity)
        x = 0
        while x < quantity:
            print("X1 is", x)
            x = x + 1

            # Generate Random Number for Booking ID.
            rand_string1 = ""
            for i in range(4):
                rand_string1 = rand_string + random.choice(string.digits)
                print("rand_string1 is : ", rand_string1)

                while int(rand_string1) < quantity:
                    print(rand_string1)
                    rand_string1 = rand_string1 + 1

            if serial.is_valid():

                serial.save(
                    booking_id=rand_string1, cus_name=request.user, created_by=request.user
                )
                token = get_tokens_for_user(request.user)

                return Response({'token': token, 'msg': 'Data Entry Successful',
                             }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serial.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Jason Input Data

```
{

"date": "2022-04-17",
"loading_date_time": "2022-02-02",
"unloading_date_time": "2022-02-02",
"ph_number": "345345345",
"cargo_weight": 4,
"quantity": 4,
"vehicle_type": "-",
"loading_address": "fgdfg",
"unloading_address": "dfgdfg"

}
```

above quantity depends on user decision. I want to that if the user put any digits in this quantity field then my code copying same input too many times. but my written code is not working. it only saves a single time.

thank you

Comment: instead of loops within loops write new methods and call them instead. It will simplify debugging

Comment: can you explain an example please ?

Comment: Can u explain this line "I want to that if the user put any digits in this quantity field then my code copying same input too many times"? , what the expected result looks like if you return the quantity response?

Comment: dear @FaisalNazik  sorry for the late, for example, if the user puts 4 that means he needs 4 bookings which creates 4-row record in the Database. but the customer is the same. thank you

Comment: Then you need a separate function to update the quantity, Like Check, if the same obj exists with the relationships to the user.,  and then update with the new value of quantity with PUT or PATCH request. Also, you need a foreign key into the Booking model to the user, to get filter out the object related to the requested user is exists or not.

Comment: Loop won't work in this scenario, you just need a separate function with .save() call and invoke it when user wants to change the quantity.

Comment: @FaisalNazik it's not updated to the existing record. I want to do it first attempt when the user put quantity, then the data saved into the database 4 times at a time. and foreign keys are not mattered at this time. because my goal is to save the data to the database. again I told you that any user can make a booking for one or more vehicles at the same time by using the quantity field. thank you